# Cannot find proper value in mapped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel-blade

here is my code:

```php
               <tbody>
                  @foreach ($meals as $keys=>$meal)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$keys+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{$meal->date}}</td>
                        @php
                          $detailsmeals= json_decode($meal->mealdetails);                                            
                        @endphp
                        @for ($i = 0; $i < count($detailsmeals->breakfasts); $i++)
                            <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">{{$detailsmeals->breakfasts[$i]}}</td>
                            <td class="lunch text-center table-info">{{$detailsmeals->lunchs[$i]}}</td>
                            <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">{{$detailsmeals->dinners[$i]}}</td>                       
                        @endfor              
                      </tr>
                      
                  @endforeach
                  <script>
                    const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
                    const outputArray = () => Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(tr => ({
                              break: tr.querySelector('.breakfast').innerText,
                              lunch: tr.querySelector('.lunch').innerText,
                              dinner: tr.querySelector('.dinner').innerText
                          }));
                    console.log(outputArray());
              </script>
                </tbody>
```

and my output is: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kARRk.jpg) only first break, lunch, dinner array of each row, how can I find all break, lunch, dinner array value of each row, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is because you're using `querySelector()`, which returns only a single element, when you need to select multiple elements with the same class in the target `tr`.

To fix this you can use the same pattern you did to select the `tr` themselves, ie. use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the target elements within the row and then `map()` it to an array with the content you need. Here's a working example of how to do this:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
const outputArray = () => [...tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')].map(tr => ({
  break: [...tr.querySelectorAll('.breakfast')].map(b => b.innerText),
  lunch: [...tr.querySelectorAll('.lunch')].map(l => l.innerText),
  dinner: [...tr.querySelectorAll('.dinner')].map(d => d.innerText)
}));
console.log(outputArray());
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">1</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">2</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">3</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">4</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">5</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">6</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">7</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">8</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">9</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">8</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">7</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">6</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">5</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">4</td>
      <td class="breakfast text-center table-primary">3</td>
      <td class="lunch text-center table-info">2</td>
      <td class="dinner text-center table-secondary">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the use of the spread selector (`[...obj]`) to build the arrays instead of `Array.from()`. Both will work, just that the former is slightly less verbose.

Note for future reference if the server-side logic which creates your HTML isn't relevant to the problem, as the Laravel isn't in this case, it's much simpler for those attempting to diagnose your issue if you just paste the HTML output.